# Animations all starting and ending at the same time?

Tags: animation, svg

Using JavaScript to dynamically add and animate text in a specific group in SVG, I'm getting a very bothersome problem that just doesn't make any sense to me. Based on the documentation, each `animate` element should individually affect only their direct parent element, which is in this case each individual text element. The problem is that, say I create one animated text element at 0s and another at 1s, and the animation for both of them lasts 2s. The one started at 1s will be halfway through its animation. Then, to make matters worse, every `animate` thereafter is basically stuck at the end of their cycle.

I've tried setting `begin="indefinite"` and firing it off with `element.beginElement()`, but this produces the same problem. I've checked the structure using Chrome's element inspector and there isn't any problem--every `animate` is inside of a `text` and every `text` is inside of the `g`.

Why is it doing this and how do I make each `animate` unique?

Comment: Please post a full example, e.g on jsfiddle.net.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a LOT of fiddling I managed to find a very choppy workaround by calculating the time offset between when the document was loaded and when the `animate` element is created, setting the `begin` attribute to that amount divided by 1000.

```
starttime=+new Date
begin=(+new Date-starttime)/1000
```

I would still like a better solution, however... is there any more efficient way to make an `animate` element begin when it's created rather than recording and calculating timestamps? At the very least I'd like to use `wallclock()` because that'd save the choppy calculations, but I can't get that to work.

Edit: I've found a better solution which works well: SVG.getCurrentTime()

Comment: it will helpful for others to learn if you post your problem in fiddle.